# Testing ActionBar Background Color

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-actionbar

I am starting to unit testing my Android code. However, I am facing a problem of how to test the background of ActionBar. I set the action bar color using the following:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_green</item>
</style>
```

So, how to load the style in code and check for the background color so I can test it?

Answer (score 0):

In your application manifest make sure you have android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
Or whatever you decide to name your custom theme.

Comment: I am asking about testing not how to set it!

Comment: This is how you would load it. Define it in the manifest and run the app. I guess I don't understand the question.